# Rails: decrement attribute in table when other record is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, transactions, callback

So I have two models: **Product** and **Sale**. they are related via a **has_many :trough** association and both have the same attributes and attribute names (sale has one more tough):

**THE CODE SNIPPETS:**

```
# Product Model

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :qty, :color, :name, :price, :size, :type, :code
    has_many :orders
    has_many :sales, :through => :orders
end 

# Sale Model

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :qty, :color, :name, :salesman_name, :price, :size, :type, :code
    has_many :orders
    has_many :productos, :through => :orders
 end
```

What I want to do is to **decrement** the *Products>Quantity* attribute of a specific record (product) every time a new Sale is created with it's name on it... The substraction must be equal to the value of "qty" set in the new sale creation in relation with the created product...

The app is a very simple inventory system where I track **stock items** and sales, let's give a pratical example: Imagine I have a product called "Socks" in the **Products** Database and I have "30" as the **qty** attribute of that product, Then someone sells **two socks** (creates a new sale with 2 socks in the app): in that case I want the value of "Socks" to be updated to 28 in the Products database automatically.

I've been reading and I think this may can be accomplished with an after_create callback in the sale model with an ActiveRecord transaction, but I'm not sure how to implement this, Can someone help me?
By the way, I was thinking about using something similar to this thing here:

```
after_create :decrement_stock

  def decrement_stock
    Sale.transaction do
      Product.transaction do
        @substraction = product.sale(params[:qty])
          product.update_attributes!(:qty => @qty - @substraction)
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm pretty sure it isn't going to work, Please Point me in the right directions... I've been struggling with this one a little.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rebuild this associations and models

What I'd do is to have this models (a little bit different than yours):

Salesman

```
class Salesman < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :last_name, :name
  has_many :sales
end
```

Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :qty
  has_many :product_sales
end
```

Sale

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :salesman
  has_many :product_sales
end
```

And here's the trick

Model ProductSale

```
class ProductSale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale
  belongs_to :product
  attr_accessible :qty

  after_create :decrement_stock

  def decrement_stock
    self.product.update_attribute("qty", (product.qty - self.qty))
  end
end
```

There you have Sale that `belongs_to` salesman.

Sale `has_many` `product_sales`

and `product_sales` belongs_to `product` and `sales` that way in one sale you have multiple product

Then when a `ProductSale` is saved there's the callback `after_create :decrement_stock`

And you can update the attribute for that specific product.

Remember that you'll have a quantity for each product and not for the whole sale.

Here's a little example I set up for you:

https://github.com/Mr-Nizzle/inventory